# how to work with activity indicator until listview loaded xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am binding `listview` from web service, now some time `listview` take time to load depend on internet connection, i need `activity indicator` keep running until `listview` is load.
here is my code

xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="ReportListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportList}"
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="9" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Lavender">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="Medium" WidthRequest="10000" TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                </StackLayout
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<ActivityIndicator HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False" x:Name="activity"/>
```

i am working like this which is absolutely not correct

.cs

```
activity.IsVisible = true;
activity.IsRunning = true;
wait.IsVisible = true;
progressControl.IsVisible = true;
ReportListView.IsVisible = false;
Task.Delay(5000);
BindingContext = new MainViewModel();

activity.IsVisible = false;
activity.IsRunning = false;
wait.IsVisible = false;
progressControl.IsVisible = false;

ReportListView.IsVisible = true;
```

with this code `activity indicator` run for 5 sec and disappear and `listview` load depends on network connection.
How can i work where activity indicator keep running until `listview` load?

Comment: Bind your `IsVisible` and `IsRunning` to something that gets set from the actual networking code instead of using `Task.Delay(5000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to bind the `IsVisible` property of the `ActivityIndicator` to some `IsBusy` or `IsLoading` property of your view model.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ReportListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportList}">
    ...
</ListView>
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
bool isBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get => isBusy; 
    set 
    { 
        isBusy = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }
}

async Task LoadItemsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        // Call your web service here
        var items = await service.LoadSomthingAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

In this case, each time when you set `IsBusy` to `true`, the app will show a loading indicator.

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml, you should bind the IsRunning property of your ActivityIndicator to your listview

```
<ListView x:Name="ReportListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportList}"
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="9" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="Lavender">
                <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="Medium" WidthRequest="10000" TextColor="Blue" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
            </StackLayout
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ActivityIndicator HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" 
 IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReportListView}, Path=IsLoading}" 
 x:Name="activity"/>
```

Then, in your code behind, on initialization, set the `IsVisible`, `IsEnabled` and `IsRunning` to true

```
For example

public ListViewPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        activity.IsVisible = true;
        activity.IsRunning = true;
        activity.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

You can then handle hiding your activityIndicator as below

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        ReportListView.ItemsSource = //your items;
        reportIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        reportIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        reportIndicator.IsEnabled = false;

        base.OnAppearing();            
    }
```

Comment: @OlorunfemiAjibulu not picking on you, but that statement shows where good modern programming has gone. All terminology and standards and no depth. Knowing the terminology for MVVM but not knowing how to take this example and build a working MVVM version of it.